# Using ImportXML to pull URL and anchor of link containing the string

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use ImportXML in Google Sheets to pull URL and anchor of link containing the string. Problem is that I want to avoid having string hardcoded and want it to be pulled from another cell.

Hardcoded example:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.debian.org/mirror/list", "//a/@href[contains(., 'about')]")
```

Desired outcome (using **A2** *instead of* **about**):

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.debian.org/mirror/list", "//a/@href[contains(., A2)]")
```

I tried putting A2 in quotes but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.debian.org/mirror/list", "//a/@href[contains(.,'"&A2&"' )]")
```

ie single quotes (as before) around double quotes around `&`s.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. What's the deal with &'s? When do I use those? are those some sort of escapes?

Comment: Also, how can i limit the amount of content I get with this call because ocassionally cell with result gets error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3" meaning that content would span across more than one cells e.g. there are more than 2 links containing the string i provided. How can I limit it or make bottom rows move down automatically?

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah, limiting to 1 cell/row via ARRAY_CONSTRAIN did the trick.